# Some articles do not show in references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a question about the process of bitex, I have about 30 articles, which I want to add into reference using bibtex (I use Texshop). After running both file .tex and .bib. There are only 25 articles in the reference. I do not know why the last 5 articles do not show like other 25. Here are the code of some articles, which do not show in reference.

```
@ARTICLE{6,
author = {{Tetcos Engineering}},
Journal = {whatever},
month = {01},
year = {2012},
pages = {1},
Number = {1},
Publisher = {viet},
title = {Comparison of TCP congestion control algorithms},
Volume = {Internet-draft}
}

@ARTICLE{12,
author = {Chromium Projects},
year = {2012},
month = {01},
pages = {1},
title = {Quic at 10000 feet}
}

@ARTICLE{14,
author = {IETF QUIC WG},
year = {2012},
month = {01},
pages = {},
title = {Various Base Drafts for Quic protocols}
}
```

Is it because the articles do not have enough information?
Thanks for your helps.

V

Comment: Standard behavior is that items only show up in the bibliography if they are actually used with \cite{}. So did you cite them?

Comment: i did not. Thanks for your advices. It is really amateur problem.

Comment: the bib file should be thought of as a database of all possible references, some people routinely have thousands of entries of every document they encounter , or standard bib files for their subject area then in the document you cite the ones you need,

Comment: I guess we all had similar problems when we started. There are ways to force LaTeX to show all entries, but - at least in academic context - having bibliography entries for uncited items is often seen as misconduct.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please prepare a minimal working example showing the problem; it'll be much easier for us to figure out what's going on, and it might even solve your problem for you.  Good luck!

Comment: Do you have `\cite{14}` in your document?